# Backup seguro usando MySQL e C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, banco-de-dados, backup

Minha aplicação é C# e BD é MySQL, guando eu faço o *backup* ele cria um `arquivo.sql`. Esse `arquivo.sql` pode ser editado facilmente em um bloco de notas, ou outro editor qualquer, deixando assim meu bd bem veraneável, como eu posso fazer para que ninguém edite meu BD e que somente o usuário cadastro por mim no servidor consiga abrir esse *backup*.

Segue a linha de *backup* do MySQL que uso em C#

```
public void Backup(string Caminho) //Backup a MySQL database
    {
        string constring = _StringConexao;
        string CaminhoBackup = Caminho + "\\databases.sql";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    mb.ExportToFile(CaminhoBackup);
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você protege o banco de dados? Como? O DB está em um servidor que o ninguém tem acesso livre? Ou está na mesma máquina da aplicação?

Comment: Opa bigown, Primeiro muito obrigado pelo retorno. Sim o servidor ficará em um servidor isolado. Mas, temos que lembrar que aplicações distribuídas comercialmente, é o usuário final que instala tudo. OU seja ele so avança pelo instalador. Cade ao ADS deixar tudo protegido. Sei que não existe a tal segurança, na verdade nós trancamos a porta para dificultar a entrar, se o ladrão quiser ele entrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu banco de dados não ficará vulnerável por causa disto. O banco de dados e este arquivo com o código SQL dele são coisa diferentes e não relacionadas.

Você quer proteger o *backup* para que ninguém mexa? Não dê acesso a ele para nenhum usuário. Não exponha essa possibilidade no aplicativo. Esta é a forma correta de fazer isto.

Se o banco de dados está em um servidor protegido, faça a rotina que gera o arquivo de *backup* rodar só neste servidor. Se for o caso agende uma tarefa.

Se o banco de dados não está em um servidor isolado sem acesso dos usuários, então você já está com problemas bem maiores que proteger o *backup*.

Se insistir em fazer o *backup* no cliente, mesmo que vindo de um servidor protegido, será que não tem outras vulnerabilidades? Não adianta se preocupar em proteger algo secundário se o principal tem problemas. E é muito comum ter problemas. Quem não é especialista em segurança costuma deixar passar várias falhas que não são óbvias. Em geral elas acabam não causando problemas se estiver em ambiente mais controlado (interno).

Se achar que ainda deve fazer isto, pode usar criptografia *builtin* da classe que você está usando.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd)) {
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    mb.ExportInfo.EnableEncryption = true;
    mb.ExportInfo.EncryptionPassword = "qwerty";
    mb.ExportToFile(@"C:\backup.sql");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/MySqlBackup.cs).

Veja a [documentação](https://github.com/adriancs2/MySqlBackup.Net/wiki/Using-Encryption).

Este exemplo também mostra a maneira correta de usar a conexão. Não precisa fechar. Ela fecha sozinha.

Se alguém tiver acesso à senha e isto é mais fácil do que parece poderá ter acesso à informação.

Agora a linguagem permite escrever assim:

```
using var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand());
using car mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd));
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
mb.ExportInfo.EnableEncryption = true;
mb.ExportInfo.EncryptionPassword = "qwerty";
mb.ExportToFile(@"C:\backup.sql");
```

Comment: Valeu pela dica. Isso é apenas para dificultar o acesso as informações, afinal um BD é o mais precioso de uma aplicação. fazer o backup segura evita problemas com cliente final. Valeu bom dia